# Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0. error while installing some libraries

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-drawer

I am trying to create one react native app with Drawer navigation with menu in header using stack navigation like below

[image]

I have installed packages like below
1.npm install react-navigation
2.npm add react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens@^1.0.0-alpha.23
3.npm add react-navigation-drawer

After that it's working as expected like below for drawer menu 
[image]
then am trying to create menu in header by using stack navigation after executing npm install react-navigation-stack am getting below error while running app

[image]

sometimes after installing react-native-vector-icons also am getting same error, please help in this thanks in advance

Comment: I can see the error; have you tried using  GRADLEW clean?

Comment: you are using npx to run the app? and you are on Windows OS?

Comment: join React Native chat room here at StackOverflow; come let's solve this: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203966/react-native

Comment: Hi Rizwan, am very new to React-native i don't know about GRADLEW, yes am using Windows OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this;

open your cmd, navigate to your project directory

```
cd into android
```

then
run

```
./gradlew clean
```

then re-run the app or install the package you want like the ICONS one! and try

```
npx react-native run-android
```

that should help;

**otherwise,** see this [**link**](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex) and follow steps to install **multi dex** and then repeat the above-said steps!

> as a Side Note: you should!  update android studio, plugins and
>   rebuild the app with latest android and Gradle